# Не работает justify-content space-between

Tags: html, css

Не работает это свойство. Вот пример:

```css
.tasks__list-item-todo-buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between; 
}
 
 .tasks__list-item-todo-buttons-row {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
}

.users__list-item-action-btn-edit {
  background-color: #0059ff;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.users__list-item-action-btn-delete {
  background-color: darkred;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.tasks__list-item-todo-buttons-form-button {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="tasks__list-item-todo-buttons">
                        <div class="tasks__list-item-todo-buttons-row">
                            <form action="post" class="tasks__list-item-todo-buttons-form">
                                <input type="text" class="tasks__list-item-todo-buttons-form-input" name="status" value="Новая" hidden>
                                <button class="tasks__list-item-todo-buttons-form-button">Новая</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tasks__list-item-todo-buttons-row">
                            <form method="post" action="/todo/tasks/delete" class="users__list-item-actions-edit">
                                <input type="text" name="id" value="" hidden>
                                <button class="users__list-item-action-btn-delete" onclick="return confirm('Вы уверены?')">Удалить</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Смотрите, что самое интересное, тут работает, а вот что у меня получается: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А чего вы хотите добиться? Чтобы кнопка "Удалить" была слева? Попробуйте самой кнопке удалить прописать `margin-left: auto`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По Вашему скрину не очень всё понятно, но могу предположить, что тут Ваш код работает, потому что Вы сюда скопировали лишь его фрагмент. А на скрине видно, что приведённый Вами фрагмент, помимо того, что он flex-контейнер, и сам является flex-элементом своего родителя.

И вот здесь, как раз и не ясно: возможно, свойство `space-between` таки работает, но `tasks__list-item-todo-buttons` просто слишком узкий и занимает по ширине как раз только эти две кнопки (грубо говоря, он стал не блочным, а строчным, когда поместился в flex-контейнер)?
Советую обратить внимание на родительский `div` с классом `.tasks__list-item-todo-actions`

Comment: Действительно, прописал .tasks__list-item-todo-buttons { width: 1000px }, все как надо работает, а как исправить этот момент, если у меня стоит display: flex, и display: block я прописать не могу ему?

Comment: Идея в том, чтобы нужный блок увеличить на всю ширину. Из того, что я вижу на Вашем скрине, попробуйте для Вашего блока ```.tasks__list-item-todo-buttons``` прописать свойство ```flex: 1 1 auto;``` - таким образом, flex-элемент должен занять всю ширину своего родителя

Comment: работает, спасибо!!!